# Plotly installation fails to establish new connection

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, installation, plotly, http-proxy

I usually use a proxy at my workplace such that I have:

```
C:\myPath>echo %https_proxy%
http://myUser:myPassword@myProxy:myPort
```

Now I am at home (it means.. no proxy!) and I am trying to install a package ("plotly"):

```
C:\myPath>conda install -c plotly plotly=1.3.2
Fetching package metadata ...

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None
for url <None>

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /plot
ly/win-64/repodata.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3
.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000004D786A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] g
etaddrinfo failed',)))",),)
```

In order to remove the proxy settings without removing the environment variables I tried:

```
set http_proxy = ""
set https_proxy= ""
```

but the situation does not change.
I have also tried:

```
C:\myPath>pip install plotly
Collecting plotly
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot conne
ct to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0
x0000000003C6C400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/plotly/
```

The questions are:
- is the problem my proxy settings?
- if it is, how can I change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved in a very simple way. The mistake was in the way I removed the proxy. I set:

```
C:\myPath>set https_proxy=
```

and the command

```
C:\myPath>conda install -c plotly plotly=1.3.2
```

worked!

WARNING: the commands `http(s)_proxy=` have to contain **no blank spaces**.